# System.getProperty("os.name") on linux reads which file?

Tags: java

Generally we read a file from `/etc/os-release` or `/etc/redhat-release`. I am not sure from where this `System.getProperty("os.name")` gets its value.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/solaris/native/java/lang/java_props_md.c#l399) (open JDK 7)

```
struct utsname name;
uname(&name);
sprops.os_name = strdup(name.sysname);
```

As you can see, a `uname` command allows to guess the os name. More precisely, the kernel name from uname is used (`uname -s`)

so `Linux` for the Debian Jessie that I'm using.